# How can this contradiction be avoided and be corrected?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, reference-frames, orbital-motion

Suppose we have a situation with a massive planet and a rocket is sent from a height $h$ with speed $v$ greater than escape speed. Now initial angular momentum is finite as $mvh$, but as we know it will follow a hyperbolic path so at infinity angular momentum would be $mv'r$, where $r$ tends to infinity, so $v'$ should tend to zero but as $v'$ is finite may or maybe not be close to zero because $v$ is larger than the escape speed. So we get that at infinity its angular momentum is infinite. Since angular momentum needs to be conserved, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a hyperbolic orbit, angular momentum is not $L = mvr$ - that's only true in a circular orbit where your velocity and radius are orthogonal to each other.

For other orbits, you have to use the actual vector equation $\vec L = m \vec r \times \vec v$. If you write down the actual velocity function $\vec v(\vec r)$ along your hyperbolic orbit and examine $\vec r \times \vec v(\vec r)$, you'll find it is still constant along the trajectory because the angle between the $v$ and the $r$ changes as well as their magnitudes.

Comment: intially angle is 90° between v and h

Comment: Oh i see wym , u mean at infinity the sintheta term will tend to zero making it finite again ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks now got it :)